# Fetching notifications on socket event

Tags: typescript, websocket, notifications, novu

How can I set up a Mantine popup notification to be displayed when a new notification is received from Novu?

Here is what I'm trying to do (code below):

```
const { socket: novuSocket } = useSocket();
  const { notifications, refetch, markAsSeen } = useNotifications();

  const handleNewNotification = async () => {
    await refetch();
    console.log(notifications)
    notifications.forEach((n) => {
      showNotification({
        id: n._id,
        title: 'New Notification',
        message: `${n.content}`,
        autoClose: false,
        onClose: ({ id }) => {
          markAsSeen(id);
        }
      })
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (novuSocket) {
      novuSocket.on('unseen_count_changed', async (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        handleNewNotification();
      });
    }

    return () => {
      if (novuSocket) {
        novuSocket.off('unseen_count_changed');
      }
    }
  }, [novuSocket])
```

Yet when I log out of the notifications, it's just an empty array, even after the refetch() call. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`useNotifications().notifications` returns the currently displayed notifications, which in your case is always empty (assuming you don't show notifications in other components).

Also, it doesn't make sense to use `forEach` on the currently displayed notifications.

You just directly show the notification with `showNotification`:

```
const handleNewNotification = async (notificationData: any) => {
    await refetch();
    showNotification({
      id: notificationData._id,
      title: 'New Notification',
      message: `${notificationData.content}`,
      autoClose: false,
      onClose: ({ id }) => {
        markAsSeen(id);
      }
    })
  })
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (novuSocket) {
      novuSocket.on('unseen_count_changed', async (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        handleNewNotification(data);
      });
    }
}
```